Inactive button still functioning when being clicked in flutter
I have a button in my app, whenever a user clicks on the button in a day, he won't be able to click on the button again for the whole day, and when he clicks on the button, the button will be inactive all throughout the day and will be active tomorrow. i saved the time and date of users last clicked on firestore but my issues here is when the button is inactive, it also execute, please below is my code, what am i getting wrong here. i will really appreciate any help
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkButtonStatus();
  }

verifyAccount() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('http://'),
     headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
            "Accept": "application/json",
          },
    
    body:{
       "accountNo": widget.valueAccountNo,
       "accountName": widget.valueAccountName,
       "bankName": widget.valueBankName,
    });
var data = await json.decode(json.encode(response.body));  
 if(data == "Error"){               
        }
        else{
          //Get Your ERROR message's here
      
        }
  }

  Future<void> _checkButtonStatus() async {
      User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    _uid = user!.uid;
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
          await _firestore.collection('Withdrawals').doc(_uid).get();
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        Timestamp lastPressed = documentSnapshot['date'];
        DateTime lastPressedDate = lastPressed.toDate();
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
        Duration difference = currentDate.difference(lastPressedDate);

        setState(() {
          _isButtonActive = difference.inHours >= 24;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error checking button status: $e");
    }
  }


Future<void> _handleButtonPress() async {
    try {
      await _firestore.collection('Withdrawals').doc(_uid).set({
        'date': Timestamp.now(),
      });
      setState(() {
        _isButtonActive = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error handling button press: $e");
    }
  }



 child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(_isButtonActive ? 'Continue':'Disabled'),
           onPressed: _isButtonActive ? () async {
            await _handleButtonPress();
            verifyAccount();
          } : null,

        ),

It shouldn't verify or go to verifyAccount() method if the button is inactive, please is there anything am missing or am not doing well please
   


In your function initState(), you are not awaiting _checkButtonStatus(). This means that initState() most likely returns before the completion of _checkButtonStatus().

So what should I do so that when the button is inactive it won't run verifyAccount() function please

The standard way of building a widget that depends on a Future is by using a FutureBuilder.

Instead of Future<void> _checkButtonStatus() you could have something like: Future<bool>_getButtonStatus() and use this value to either disable/enable the button.

I'm confused can you please explain more by writing a code so that I will understand, please

My suggestion was to store the state of the button as a Future<bool> and refactor your function _checkButtonStatus() into _getButtonStatus() a function that returns a future value.
This also removes the problem of calling setState from initState.
The example below is adapted from the solution shown at: FutureBuilder. It can be copy/pasted and run in a dartpad.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SimpleApp());

class SimpleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyButton(),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyButton> createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {

  // State of button is stored as a Future<bool>.
  late Future<bool> _isButtonActive;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isButtonActive = _getButtonStatus();
  }

  Future<bool> _getButtonStatus() async {
    // User? user = _auth.currentUser;
    // _uid = user!.uid;
    try {
      // DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
      //     await _firestore.collection('Withdrawals').doc(_uid).get();
      // if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      //   Timestamp lastPressed = documentSnapshot['date'];
      //   DateTime lastPressedDate = lastPressed.toDate();
      //   DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
      //   Duration difference = currentDate.difference(lastPressedDate);
      //   return difference.inHours >= 24;

      // For testing: Remove line below
      return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => true);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error checking button status: $e");
      return Future<bool>.value(false);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleButtonPress() async {
    try {
      // await _firestore.collection('Withdrawals').doc(_uid).set({
      //   'date': Timestamp.now(),
      // });
      setState(() {
        _isButtonActive = Future.value(false);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error handling button press: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: _isButtonActive,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        debugPrint('building');
        List<Widget> children;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          children = <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: snapshot.data! ? _handleButtonPress : null,
                child: Text(snapshot.data! ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled')),
          ];
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          children = <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.error_outline,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 60,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            ),
          ];
        } else {
          children = const <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Initializing button...'),
            ),
          ];
        }
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: children,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


do it like that
onPressed: _isButtonActive ? () async {
            await _handleButtonPress();
            verifyAccount();
          } :(){},

instead of passing null pass an empty function.
